# Indenting `cl-flet` etc

Tags: indentation, cl-lib

Is there a way to indent `cl-flet`, `cl-labels` etc. using the CL style [*without* resorting to `(setq lisp-indent-function #'common-lisp-indent-function)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767189/864684)?

`cl-indent.el` claims that:

> `common-lisp-indent-function` is also a suitable function for indenting Emacs lisp code.

But this is far from true. It misindents the `:type`s of `defcustom`s, the docstring of `define-minor-mode`, and more.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the current codebase, [there is an open bug for it](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=9622).  Fixing it should be a matter of copying the functionality from `cl-indent.el` without getting the misindenting of `defcustom`, `define-minor-mode`, etc.

Comment: `This bug report was last modified 6 years and 136 days ago.` 

Comment: @TianxiangXiong That does not mean patches aren't welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Define the indentation for a given function/macro etc. by putting the indentation spec on the function etc. symbol as property `common-lisp-indent-function`.  As one possible example:

```
(put 'cl-flet
     'common-lisp-indent-function
     '((&whole 4 &rest (&whole 1 &lambda &body)) &body))
```

Comment: But this doesn't work unless `lisp-indent-function` property is set to `common-lisp-indent-function`, right? That's what I find from my experiments.

Comment: I tried `(put 'cl-flet 'lisp-indent-function #'common-lisp-indent-function)` so that `common-lisp-indent-function` applies only applies to `cl-flet`, but that's not indenting properly either.

Answer (score 0):

The following code indents `flet` like lists.  It's not perfect, because the sublist needs to be closed, before it is recognized.

```
(setq-default lisp-indent-function 'elisp-flet-indent-function)

(defvar elisp-flet-style-macros
  (let ((macs '(flet flet* values macrolet labels)))
    (append macs (mapcar (lambda (sym)
                           (intern (format "cl-%s" (symbol-name sym))))
                         macs))))

(dolist (mac elisp-flet-style-macros)
  (put mac 'lisp-indent-function 'defun))

(defun elisp-flet-indent-function (indent-point state)
  "Handle `flet'-like lists, otherwise call `lisp-indent-function'."
  (cond
   ((ignore-errors
      (save-excursion
        (backward-up-list 3)
        (down-list)
        (when (memq (intern (thing-at-point 'symbol))
                    elisp-flet-style-macros)
          (forward-sexp 2)
          (>= (point) indent-point))))
    (lisp-indent-defform state indent-point))
   (t (lisp-indent-function indent-point state))))
```

Comment: `values` shouldn't get this special treatment, should it?